# Please welcome your new pro tem mod!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. Though it saddens me to say it, one of your moderators has decided it's time to step down. Fortunately for you, one of your fellow AI Stackers has answered the call to be your new pro tem mod:

[image: DukeZhou]

Please join me in thanking NietzscheanAI for their service and in welcoming DukeZhou!

Comment: But we haven't elected..the community is unaware!!!!...Can someone tells us what's going on here?

Comment: @quint - right. This wasn't an election. DukeZhou was *appointed* directly by the Stack Exchange team, to be a moderator pro tempore. When the site graduates, we'll have an actual election.

Answer (score 5):

I take on this responsibility with the assumption I a probably wasn't the first choice, and the awareness that I certainly can't fill NietzscheanAI's shoes.

That said, I'll do my best to fulfill my duties a *pro tem* mod *(emphasis on pro tem;)* taking my lead from the senior mods and our power-user experts, and will try to add value to the forum per my experience on the Humanities side of the AI equation.

Answer (score 2):

Goodbye, @Niet! I voted for you on the original pro tem nominations, and I was sorry to hear that you were unhappy with what was considered on topic and decided to step down - I hope you decide to still be generally active, even without the diamond.

To @DukeZhou: I've seen you around, here and over on Literature. You weren't active in the private beta, but that's excusable ;). I'm sure that you'll be able to take on your new duties and do them well. Thank you for volunteering for the position!

Comment: That last paragraph has made me think the other way.Planet earth is kinda interesting though.hands up-to you Duke.