# Please welcome another pro tem mod!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. Though it once again saddens me to say it, one of your moderators has decided it's time to step down. Another of your fellow community members here on AI SE has answered the call to be your new pro tem mod, though:

[image: Jaden Travnik]

Please join me in thanking Matthew Graves for his service and in welcoming Jaden Travnik!

Those who are keeping a close eye on meta may remember [an announcement similar to this](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/please-welcome-your-new-pro-tem-mod) not that long ago. To address some of the issues raised implicitly and explicitly there:

- Jaden, like your other mods, is a moderator [*pro tempore*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/). All Stack Exchange sites in public beta have moderators appointed by the SE staff (people like me). You'll get to elect moderators on your own if and when your site graduates.
- Graduation is, to oversimplify a bit, based primarily on question volume. We ran an analysis a couple years ago to make the process more data-driven and found a correlation between questions per day and site health. For more on that, and our philosophy, see [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) on the network meta site.

(If you have questions about graduation, please post a separate meta question.)

Comment: ,pops you always disturb my mind even though am not perfectly human!

Comment: Congratulations @Jaden! And I'm glad that you found someone else, Pops - I'm sure Jaden will do a good job ;)

Comment: You did a great job Matthew, I personally enjoyed your contribution. Congratulations Jaden. I'm very excited regarding your new position. It will be great to have you as our mod